# Novation Bass Station II

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer, synthesis, analog, bass

I recently bought a Novation Bass Station II and am finding it considerably difficult to adapt to. Most notably, I'm finding it difficult to produce relatively simple tones/timbres. What parameters will provide a good starting point from which to learn, experiment and sculpt new sounds?

Answer (score 1):

Try learning synthesis in general. Bass Station 2 is a relatively easy synth, with classic parameters. You'll need to understand what each module or function is doing. I can recommend [syntorial](http://www.syntorial.com/) for this or you can find lots of books for beginners.

When you are confident about what each module does or if you already are, try finding patches you like (not nessecarily in BS only, maybe digital synth you have) and understand what it is doing. Why is that you like it. Try to modify them and keep experimenting.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think, the difficulty I'm having is that; I seem to be simultaneously juggling all these superfluous modules, when basically; all I *really* want to do is; produce a; *simple* ***sine wave.***

Comment: sometimes less is more :))

Comment: For sure, it's just not always easy to know which positions various switches ought to be in, or if certain pots should be at 7 o'clock or 12 o'clock, and so on.